# Blank page after deployment - React app with node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

My react app is working fine on localhost and the server-side (node js) is also working fine on localhost, but when I deployed it on Heroku, it shows a blank page.

For deployment,
I did create a Procfile where I referred to the server file

```
web: node ./server/index.js
```

which also includes:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client/build'));
app.get("/*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"))
);
```

When I run the app  I get a blank page

The console I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.679eafbe.chunk.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

After searching I made sure that:

- The react app is created: npm create-react-app my-app
- I don't have homepage props in my package.json for the react app
- I did build the react app which is found under the client folder under myApp after creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.679eafbe.chunk.js:1
```

This error implies your server is returning HTML when handling `main.679eafbe.chunk.js`.

This means `express.static` probably isn't matching that path and the request is passed onto your html middleware.

This is either because `main.679eafbe.chunk.js` doesn't exist in the client/build directory or `express.static` is misconfigured.

If I were to take a guess, I'd suggest changing the `root` you pass to `express.static` to align with the path you're using in the html middleware, e.g.

```js
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build"))); // path.resolve was missing here
app.get("/*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Richard Scarrott** Solution worked for me with small changes.
I try with his solution but it didn't work for me. 
FontEnd Folder Name : **client** (React.js) 
BackEnd Folder Name : **server** (Node.js) 
I use to copy react **build** folder from **client** to **server** folder and used the code below

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname) + "/build/index.html");
});
```

But it make black Page. 
So, I used **Richard Scarrot** Codes with small changes 
The Codes works for me

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "/build"))); // path.resolve was missing here
app.get("/*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/build", "index.html"))
);
```

NOTE: I apply `gcloud app depoloy` from server folder