# React Webapp deployed on App Engine displays blank page

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Here's the the app.yaml for the deploying build pages to gcloud:

```
runtime: nodejs16
handlers:
# Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\..+)$
# Serve all static images with url ending with a image extension  
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: build/images/\1
  upload: build/images/.+\.(gif|png|jpg)$  
# Catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

Here's the build structure for the build:

[image: Public Build directory for deployment]

Here are the build scripts for the project:

```
 "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
```

When I deploy app on the gcloud here's the blank page I can find the logo png url but it's not being loaded with other components:

[image: Deployed on appspot]

```
https://mintdapp.uc.r.appspot.com/build/images/logo.png
```

is the image address of the logo

Comment: Hi Sagar, so you are using node.js or react.js while deploying the app.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar I am using yarn to deploy the project.

Comment: And you app.yaml is in which language, is it node.js as per above code snippet?

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar I am able to run the production files from build folder in localhost on gcloud but receiving blank page via `gcloud app deploy`

Comment: Sagar,By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.May be this would be need to set.Also check the details available here Check this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/.
Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66076256/blank-page-after-deployment-react-app-with-node       and   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119725/create-react-app-build-does-not-work-correctly?rq=1

Comment: Sagar, was the information helpful or are you looking for something.

Comment: Sagar, I checked https://mintdapp.uc.r.appspot.com link and it loads the webpage,is there anything else which is broken you may update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Each [service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine) in your app has its own app.yaml file, which acts as a descriptor for its deployment. You must first create the app.yaml file for the default service before you can create and deploy app.yaml files for additional services within your app.                                                                                                            For Node.js, the app.yaml is required to contain at least a runtime entry. For a brief overview, see [Defining Runtime Settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)  .                                                                          To handle deep links, you need a catch-all rule at the end to always serve index.html . However, before that, you need a rule which maps all your static content.

```
runtime: nodejs16 # or another supported version
instance_class: F2
env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "example-gcs-bucket"
handlers:
- url: /example1
  static_dir: example1
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

You may also try rearranging your static assets in a folder rather than under the root. Create a directory named "staticfiles" and move all html files to it(except the homepage.html) example as below; and then try redeploying

```
    url: /(.*\.html) 
    mime_type: text/html 
    static_files: staticfiles/\1 
    upload: staticfiles/(.*\.html)
```

Comment: It still doesn’t work